# Simple Console Snake game C++

Tags: c++, game, console, snake-game

I recently started learning C++ and have made a very simple Console-based Snake Game, I would like to have some feedback on improvements.

You might notice the obvious delay in clearing and printing of the screen, as I did not use `system("cls")` since it was stated as 'evil' and 'bad'.
 I printed a bunch of newlines instead as suggested [in a forum that I had read](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/10515/).
(Didn't use NCurses since it was an overkill for my simple snake game)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>
#include <conio.h>

#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

enum Direction2D {
    UNDEFINED = 0,
    LEFT,
    RIGHT,
    UP,
    DOWN
};

bool IsOppositeOf(const Direction2D& first, const Direction2D& second) {
    // Feedback for a more elegant approach, thanks.
    bool isOpposite = false;
    if (first == LEFT && second == RIGHT) {
        isOpposite = true;
    }
    else if (first == RIGHT && second == LEFT) {
        isOpposite = true;
    }
    else if (first == UP && second == DOWN) {
        isOpposite = true;
    }
    else if (first == DOWN && second == UP) {
        isOpposite = true;
    }

    return isOpposite;
}

struct Vector2D
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

// Since we are printing downwards, 'up' would technically be down.
Vector2D const Up = { 0, -1 };
Vector2D const Down = { 0, 1 };

Vector2D const Left = { -1, 0 };
Vector2D const Right = { 1, 0 };

Vector2D const Zero = { 0, 0 };

#pragma region Vector2D_Operators

bool operator ==(const Vector2D& first, const Vector2D& second) {
    return (first.x == second.x) && (first.y == second.y);
}

Vector2D operator +(const Vector2D& first, const Vector2D& second) {
    return { (first.x + second.x), (first.y + second.y) };
}

Vector2D operator -(const Vector2D& first, const Vector2D& second) {
    return { (first.x - second.x), (first.y - second.y) };
}

#pragma endregion

bool gameOver;

int playerScore;

int width;
int height;

Vector2D snakeHeadPosition;
Vector2D currentFruitPosition;

Direction2D currentSnakeMovingDirection;

// I'm assuming the length of the tail doesn't go beyond 256.
// Accepting feedback on how I could do this more elegantly.
Vector2D tailPositions[256];

int tailLength;

#pragma region Util

void ClearCinInput() {
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}

template <typename T>
void RequestForValidInputValue(T &receivingArg, std::string errorMsg) {
    // Ask for input while the input is not of the correct type.
    while (!(std::cin >> receivingArg)) {
        std::cout << errorMsg << std::endl;
        ClearCinInput();
    }
}

#pragma region Request_For_YesNo

void PrintRespectiveYesNoTextByFirstRun(bool firstRun) {
    if (firstRun) {
        std::cout << "(Y/N)" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Please input either 'Y' or 'N'." << std::endl;
    }
}

bool CheckIfValidYesNoInput(std::string input) {
    return (input == "Y" || input == "N");
}

bool AskUserForYesNo() {
    std::string userInput = "";

    bool loopFirstRun = true;

    // Ask for input again while the input was not a confirmation.
    do {
        PrintRespectiveYesNoTextByFirstRun(loopFirstRun);

        RequestForValidInputValue(userInput, "ERROR: Please input 'Y' or 'N' ");
        loopFirstRun = false;
    } while (!CheckIfValidYesNoInput(userInput));

    return userInput == "Y";
}

#pragma endregion

void ClearScreen() {
    // SLOW
    std::cout << std::string(100, '\n');
}

void PlaceFruitRandomlyInPlayingField() {
    currentFruitPosition = { rand() % width, rand() % height };
}

#pragma endregion

void HandleFruitEating() {
    ++tailLength;
    ++playerScore;
    PlaceFruitRandomlyInPlayingField();
}

bool SnakeEatingFruit() {
    return snakeHeadPosition == currentFruitPosition;
}

bool SnakeHeadTouchedTail() {
    bool touchedTail = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < tailLength; ++i) {
        if (tailPositions[i] == snakeHeadPosition) {
            touchedTail = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return touchedTail;
}

bool SnakeHeadTouchedBorder() {
    int x = snakeHeadPosition.x;
    int y = snakeHeadPosition.y;

    return (x > width || x < 0 || y > height || y < 0);
}

void UpdateSnakePositionByCurrentMoveDirection() {
    switch (currentSnakeMovingDirection) {
    case LEFT:
        snakeHeadPosition = snakeHeadPosition + Left;
        break;
    case RIGHT:
        snakeHeadPosition = snakeHeadPosition + Right;
        break;
    case UP:
        snakeHeadPosition = snakeHeadPosition + Up;
        break;
    case DOWN:
        snakeHeadPosition = snakeHeadPosition + Down;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

void UpdateSnakeTailPositions() {
    Vector2D prevPosition = tailPositions[0];
    Vector2D temp;
    tailPositions[0] = snakeHeadPosition;

    for (int i = 1; i < tailLength; ++i) {
        temp = tailPositions[i];
        tailPositions[i] = prevPosition;
        prevPosition = temp;
    }
}

void UpdateGameLogic() {

    UpdateSnakeTailPositions();
    UpdateSnakePositionByCurrentMoveDirection();

    if (SnakeHeadTouchedBorder() || SnakeHeadTouchedTail()) {
        gameOver = true;
    }
    else if (SnakeEatingFruit()) {
        HandleFruitEating();
    }
}

#pragma region Handling_Inputs

void MoveSnakeIfValid(Direction2D newDirection) {
    if (tailLength > 0) {
        // To prevent suicidal acts by moving backwards into a tail.
        if (!IsOppositeOf(newDirection, currentSnakeMovingDirection)) {
            currentSnakeMovingDirection = newDirection;
        }
    }
    else {
        currentSnakeMovingDirection = newDirection;
    }
}

void MoveSnakeByUserInput(char inputValue) {
    Direction2D newMoveDirection;
    switch (inputValue) {
    case 'a':
        newMoveDirection = LEFT;
        break;
    case 'd':
        newMoveDirection = RIGHT;
        break;
    case 'w':
        newMoveDirection = UP;
        break;
    case 's':
        newMoveDirection = DOWN;
        break;
    default:
        newMoveDirection = UNDEFINED;
        break;
    }

    if (newMoveDirection != UNDEFINED) {
        MoveSnakeIfValid(newMoveDirection);
    }
}

bool GetKeyPressInputIfExists(char &keyPressValue) {
    if (_kbhit()) {
        keyPressValue = _getch();
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

#pragma endregion

void HandleInput() {
    char keyPressValue;
    if (GetKeyPressInputIfExists(keyPressValue)) {
        MoveSnakeByUserInput(keyPressValue);
    }
}

#pragma region Drawing_PlayField

bool PrintTailOnPositionIfNeeded(Vector2D position) {
    bool tailPrinted = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < tailLength; ++i) {
        if (position == tailPositions[i]) {
            std::cout << "o";
            tailPrinted = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return tailPrinted;
}

void PrintFruitOrSnakeOrEmptyByPosition(Vector2D position) {
    if (snakeHeadPosition == position) {
        std::cout << "O";
    }
    else if (currentFruitPosition == position) {
        std::cout << "X";
    }
    else if (!PrintTailOnPositionIfNeeded(position)) {
        std::cout << " ";
    }
}

void DrawHorizontalBorderByWidth() {
    for (int i = 0; i < width + 2; ++i) {
        std::cout << "#";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void DrawMiddleSection() {
    for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j) {
            if (j == 0) {
                std::cout << "#";
            }

            PrintFruitOrSnakeOrEmptyByPosition({ j, i });

            if (j == width - 1) {
                std::cout << "#";
            }
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

#pragma endregion

void DrawPlayingField() {
    // system("cls");
    ClearScreen();

    // Top
    DrawHorizontalBorderByWidth();

    DrawMiddleSection();
    // Bottom
    DrawHorizontalBorderByWidth();
}

void UpdateGame() {
    DrawPlayingField();
    HandleInput();
    UpdateGameLogic();
}

#pragma region Request_PlayField_Width_And_Height_From_User

#pragma region Request_For_Valid_Play_Field_Size

bool PlayingFieldSizeIsValid() {
    return (width >= 10) && (height >= 10);
}

void RequestForValidPlayingFieldSize() {
    bool loopFirstRun = true;

    // Keep asking for width and height while the given playing field is not of valid size.
    do {
        if (!loopFirstRun) {
            std::cout << "The width and height of the playing field must be at least 10 or more!";
        }

        std::cout << "Enter the gamearea's width: " << std::endl;
        RequestForValidInputValue(width, "ERROR: width must be an integer!");
        std::cout << "Enter the gamearea's height: " << std::endl;
        RequestForValidInputValue(height, "ERROR: Height must be an integer!");

        loopFirstRun = false;
    } while (!PlayingFieldSizeIsValid());
}

#pragma endregion

void RequestForPlayingFieldSize() {
    bool confirmed = false;
    do {
        RequestForValidPlayingFieldSize();

        std::cout << "Your game area will be (" << width << ", " << height << "), Confirm?" << std::endl;
        confirmed = AskUserForYesNo();

    } while (!confirmed);
}

#pragma endregion

void ClearAndInitalizeVariables() {
    tailLength = 0;
    playerScore = 0;
    gameOver = false;
    currentSnakeMovingDirection = UNDEFINED;
}

void InitializeGame() {
    ClearScreen();
    ClearAndInitalizeVariables();

    RequestForPlayingFieldSize();
    // Start in the center
    snakeHeadPosition = { (width / 2), (height / 2) };
    tailPositions[0] = snakeHeadPosition;

    PlaceFruitRandomlyInPlayingField();
}

int main() {
    // Play the game while the user wants to play again.
    do {
        InitializeGame();

        while (!gameOver) {
            UpdateGame();
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(400));
        }

        std::cout << "GAMEOVER, Your Score: " << playerScore << std::endl;

        std::cout << "Play again? ";

    } while (AskUserForYesNo());

    return 0;
}
```

Also, would anyone give me any directions on how to properly overload and make a `+=` operator for `Vector2D`?
Currently I'm doing addition as `Vector1 = Vector1 + Vector2`, as I tried to do a `+=` operator but the implementation I did had issues.

Answer (score 1):

#### Small Bug Fix

Noticed a small bug in my game, where the fruit might have a chance to spawn inside the snake.
Did a quick fix for it:

Renamed `PlaceFruitRandomlyInPlayingField` into `PlaceFruitInPlayingField`, added and changed codes:

```
bool ValidPositionForFruit(Vector2D position) {
    bool isValidPosForFruit = true;

    if (position == snakeHeadPosition) {
        isValidPosForFruit = false;
    }
    else if (PositionIsTouchingTail(position)) {
        isValidPosForFruit = false;
    }

    return isValidPosForFruit;
}

void PlaceFruitInPlayingField() {
    // Change the fruit position while the fruit's current position is not valid.
    do {
        currentFruitPosition = { rand() % width, rand() % height };
    } while (!ValidPositionForFruit(currentFruitPosition));
}
```

Finally, I renamed and refactored `SnakeHeadTouchedTail` into `PositionIsTouchingTail(Vector2D)` since my I do need to check if my new fruit's position would touch the head, and I didn't want to repeat myself:

```
bool PositionIsTouchingTail(Vector2D position) {
    bool touchedTail = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < tailLength; ++i) {
        if (tailPositions[i] == position) {
            touchedTail = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return touchedTail;
}
```

And I placed inside the `#pragma region Util` since C++ is picky about function placements.
(The region should be near the top)

Also, in `UpdateGameLogic()` function, as you might have guessed, I'm doing `PositionIsTouchingTail(snakeHeadPosition)` instead of `SnakeHeadTouchedTail()` to check if the snake's head had touched the tail.